# Why SQL Membership Database tables created by aspnet_regsql have no primary keys

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership

This question is about the tables created by aspnet_regsql for the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership database.

I am incorporating these tables and procs, etc from the database into my application database for ease of manageemnt and integration with the application data.

I notice that none of the tables have primary keys. This is a difficulty with the tools I use to create and manage entities, dto's, repository classes and validation.

Does anyone know why these tables do not have primary keys and whether adding primary keys to these tables will interfere with the operation of the baked-in stored procs that this database includes?

Thanks,

Kimball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then something must have gone wrong with your installation - in my case, all the tables in "aspnetdb" have primary keys like any serious table should have:

[image]

Try removing aspnetdb and reinstalling...

Marc